# Can we simulate a key press without an event handler?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keypress, keyboard-events

There has been a lot of discussions on Stack Overflow about [how to dispatch a keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) programmatically with JavaScript. However, they are not simulating 'real' key presses in the sense that they merely fire a predefined event handler.

What I want is to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the browser search box. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Doubt it's possible. It's one thing to override such app specific short cuts (such as for a custom html search feature) but completely another to take control of browser features outside of the window

Comment: @charlietfl yeah...I am beginning to doubt it is possible too. It would have become too handy for hackers. lol

Comment: Yup...think how annoying it would be to see the built in browser search box keep appearing and disappearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`window.find(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) does that.

In general, you're out of luck though trying to orchestrate native browser functionality from within a webpage. Browser extensions can do more.